# ¿Cómo hacer que el clic en el botón ejecute la función sin recargar?

Tags: javascript, html

como puedo hacer que al momento de dar click en el button PDF ejecute la función js y no recargue el componente, permanezca ahí

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <button type="button" (click)="generarPDF()" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-success
    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF</button>
</div>
```

```
generarPDF() {

    this.router.navigate(['/reporte-contrato/', this.contratoSeleccionado._id]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/listacontratos']);
    }, 10);
  }
```

Comment: Para darte una buena respuesta, tengo una pregunta para ti ¿Sí sabes cómo funciona el `router` y el `navigate`?

Comment: @fredyfx si, claro. Entiendo que ese esta redireccionando a esas rutas para realizar la función con éxito. Pero al dar click requiero que permanezca ahí, no se vuelva a recargar

Comment: La pregunta tal cual está, está basada en opiniones, que no te sorprenda si te la cierran. Aquí unas recomendaciones sobre cómo preguntar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 (basado en casi 7 años de estar en SOes). Edita la pregunta y coloca todo el código que tienes en el NgOnInit del componente al que llegas al ir a la ruta `reporte-contrato` y todos los métodos que sean llamados en ese método.